# Prometheus - exclude 0 values from query result

Tags: grafana, prometheus

I'm displaying Prometheus query on a Grafana table.
That's the query (`Counter` metric):

`sum(increase(check_fail{app="monitor"}[20m])) by (reason)`

The result is a table of failure reason and its count.
The problem is that the table is also showing reasons that happened 0 times in the time frame and I don't want to display them.
AFAIK it's not possible to hide them through Grafana.

I know prometheus has [comparison operators](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/operators/#comparison-binary-operators) but I wasn't able to apply them.

Answer (score 63, accepted):

I don't know how you tried to apply the comparison operators, but if I use this very similar query:

```
sum(increase(up[1d])) by (job)
```

I get a result of zero for all jobs that have not restarted over the past day and a non-zero result for jobs that have had instances restart.

If I now tack on a `!= 0` to the end of it, all zero values are filtered out:

```
sum(increase(up[1d])) by (job) != 0
```

Comment: Simple succinct answer.  I've been using comparison operators in Grafana for a long while.  Stumbled onto this post for something else unrelated, just was +1-ing this  :)

Comment: Simple, clear and working - thanks a lot. It's worth to add that if using Grafana you should set 'Connect null values' proeprty to 'always' in order to get rid of blank spaces in the graph.